# ZeroMQ: Using DEALER/ROUTER with REQ/REP but it still expects send/recv pair

Tags: zeromq

I'm using `DEALER/ROUTER` to avoid the blocking nature of REQ/REP.
I have the **`REP` code**:

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5558")

while True:
    x = socket.recv()
    print 'REQ is', x, y
    reply = 'x-%s' % x
    socket.send(reply)
    print 'REP is', reply
```

The **`REQ` part**:

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5558")

for x in xrange(10):
     socket.send(str(x))
     print 'REQ is', x
     print "REP is", socket.recv()
```

And the **broker** code:

```
import sys
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()

s1 = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
s2 = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
s2.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5558")
s1.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5559")
zmq.device(zmq.QUEUE, s1, s2)
```

When I **`send()`** twice on the `REQ` code, I get the following error:

```
zmq.error.ZMQError: Operation cannot be accomplished in current state
```

Because it still expects the communication to be request-reply pair. How can I avoid this locking nature and send and receive any number of times without waiting for a reply?

Answer (score 0):

### ZeroMQ formal patterns encapsulate their CERTAIN BEHAVIOUR.

If that particular behaviour is not the one you like, simply do not use that very one ZeroMQ Formal Scalable Communication Pattern, that does not meet your needs.

That simple.

As an example, one may try a **`PUSH/PULL`** archetype, for having an unrestricted freedom of as many `.send()`-s as one may wish to have.

May also enjoy my other posts on ZeroMQ, where one can also find a direct URL to Pieter HINTJENS' **book "Code Connected. Volume 1"** a must-read if one is seriously willing to enter a distributed-computing domain. **Worth one's time and efforts.**

Comment: req/rep along with DEALER/ROUTER is meant to avoid the blocking nature of req/rep sockets alone. That's exactly why I've posted this question because it isn't working accordingly!

Comment: @NoName Sorry, NoName, did not get your argument. Could you kindly explain, what has your comment brought as an added value to the fact, that on one side you claim a need not to have a hardwired order of calls to `.send()` / `.recv()` two-step, but do not recognise an above already provided direction towards one of several possible & feasible solutions with un-restricted tandems of `PUSH/PULL` archetypes on the other side? What have you actually wanted to say to the problem / solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A **`REQ`** socket in ZeroMQ will **always** alternate between sending and receiving. However, you can use a **`DEALER`** socket instead of a `REQ` socket in the "client" if you want to send multiple messages:

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5559")

for x in xrange(10):
     socket.send('',zmq.SNDMORE)
     socket.send(str(x))
     print 'REQ is', x

for x in xrange(10):
     print "REP is", socket.recv()
```

**Note:** Your example does not work as is since both `REQ` and `REP` connect to port 5558. I am using 5559, so in the end we have:

```
DEALER -> ROUTER -> DEALER -> REP
```